# Play [2.11] jpa transaction

Tags: jpa, playframework-2.1, transactional

I am trying the play framework with JPA hibernate, looks only can put the @Transactional on the controller class. 
I plan to create another layer Service might be used for WS or mobile client. I want to start the transaction on the Service layer instead of controller, who knows how to do it? thanks!

Comment: Are you sure about the fact that you **can't** put it somewhere else than on a Controller ? Where have you seen it ?

Comment: Yes, tried and failed
[RuntimeException: No EntityManager bound to this thread. Try to annotate your action method with @play.db.jpa.Transactional]

Comment: When you start your transaction in the controller class with a call to your service in it it doesn't fail ?

Comment: "@Transactional" in Controller class
controller->service->model(dao)  success
"@Transactional" in Service class
controller->service->model(dao)  failed with 
[RuntimeException: No EntityManager bound to this thread. Try to annotate your action method with @play.db.jpa.Transactional]

Comment: How and where do you get your EntityManager ? (using @PersistenceContext ??)

Comment: Use the normal way like this: JPA.em().merge(this) in the model class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that when you work with EntityManager from Web Service in play 2.1 you might have the same problem about @Transactional as I had when I've worked with EntityManager from Web Socket.

So you should do it as it was answered ty my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483650/play-2-1-websocket-no-entitymanager-bound-to-this-thread). I hope that it might help and that it will work for you as well.