# Play 2.1. WebSocket No EntityManager bound to this thread

Tags: java, hibernate, websocket, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I'm trying to implement WebSocket in Play 2.1. framework together with JPA using Hibernate and I'm getting following exception when I'm accessing the DB from WebSocket:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No EntityManager bound to this thread. Try to annotate your action method with @play.db.jpa.Transactional
at play.db.jpa.JPA.em(JPA.java:42)
at model.operations.DistrictOperations.isOwner(DistrictOperations.java:15)
at controllers.security.Secured.isOwnerOf(Secured.java:28)
at controllers.DistrictCommunication.initWebSocket(DistrictCommunication.java:157)
at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$20$$anonfun$apply$20.apply(routes_routing.scala:277)
at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$20$$anonfun$apply$20.apply(routes_routing.scala:277)
at play.core.j.JavaWebSocket$$anonfun$webSocketWrapper$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(JavaWebSocket.scala:20)
at play.core.j.JavaWebSocket$$anonfun$webSocketWrapper$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(JavaWebSocket.scala:14)
at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.liftedTree1$1(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:324)
at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.messageReceived(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:322)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:75)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:565)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:793)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder.messageReceived(HttpContentDecoder.java:104)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:75)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:565)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:793)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:455)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:538)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:437)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:75)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:565)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:560)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:84)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.processSelectedKeys(AbstractNioWorker.java:472)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:333)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:35)
at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:102)
at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Here is my code:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public static WebSocket<JsonNode> initWebSocket(final long id) {

    if (Secured.isOwnerOf(id)) {

        return new WebSocket<JsonNode>() {

            // Called when the Websocket Handshake is done.
            public void onReady(WebSocket.In<JsonNode> in,
                    WebSocket.Out<JsonNode> out) {



                // For each event received on the socket,
                in.onMessage(new Callback<JsonNode>() {
                    public void invoke(JsonNode event) {


                        System.out.println(event);

                    }
                });

                // When the socket is closed.
                in.onClose(new Callback0() {
                    public void invoke() {

                        System.out.println("Disconnected");

                    }
                });

                // Send a single 'Hello!' message
                ObjectNode on = Json.newObject();
                on.put("greeting", "hello");
                out.write(on);
            }

        };

    }else{
        return null;
    }
```

secured isOwnerOf() method:

```
public static boolean isOwnerOf(Long district) {
    return DistrictOperations.isOwner(district, Context.current().request().username());
}
```

and DistrictOperations.isOwner() method:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public static boolean isOwner(long district, String login){
    Query query = JPA.em().createQuery("SELECT d FROM  District d WHERE d.id = :districtId");   
    District d = (District) query.setParameter("districtId", district).getSingleResult();
    return d.getName().equals(login);
}
```

It's advising me to add @Transactional annotation which I have in my code, so my question is: Is it somehow possible to access the database via EntityManager from the WebSocket? Because it seems to me like everything else except EntityManager works fine here.

**EDIT**
I've even tried to use EntityManager inside the WebSocket, but I have still the same problem. So maybe small reformulation is how am I supposed to work with database using from WebSocket and JPA? Is it somehow possible to use both together?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Play, a `WebSocket` is not an `Action`. The `@Transactional` annotation is not taken into account because the `play.db.jpa.TransactionalAction` only intercepts `Action` calls.

In your case, you have to manually place your code in a transaction with something like :

```
boolean isOwnerOf = JPA.withTransaction(new play.libs.F.Function0<Boolean>{
    public Boolean apply() throws Throwable {
        return Secured.isOwnerOf(id);
    }
})
```

You will have to do the same if you need to access DB in your other websocket's callbacks. These callbacks will be executed in other threads and the `JPA.withTransaction()` will take care of binding an EntityManager to these threads.

Comment: is this applies if I write different threads in a controller's method? because I got same exception when I create new thread to speed up the process. The exception is "java.lang.RuntimeException: No EntityManager bound to this thread. Try wrapping this call in JPAApi.withTransaction, or ensure tpi.withTransaction, "